# KineticJS image drag, rotate and scale

Tags: image, rotation, scale, kineticjs

Im still learning but it seems everything I do does not work in getting the images to also be rotated along with being scaled and dragged.  Can someone please help me out with this.  Here is the code I am working with...

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onmousedown="return false;">
    <div style="height:1024px; width: 1280px; background-image: url(http://www.designmyprofile.com/images/graphics/backgrounds/background0172.jpg)" id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('.image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
          case 'topLeft':
            topRight.setY(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'topRight':
            topLeft.setY(anchorY);
            bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'bottomRight':
            bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
            topRight.setX(anchorX); 
            break;
          case 'bottomLeft':
            bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
            topLeft.setX(anchorX); 
            break;
        }

        image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if(width && height) {
          image.setSize(width, height);
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: '#666',
          fill: '#ddd',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
          group.setDraggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
          group.setDraggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
          this.setStrokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }
        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      function initStage(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 1280,
          height: 1024
        });
        var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 270,
          y: 100,
          draggable: true
        });
        var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 100,
          y: 110,
          draggable: true
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        /*
         * go ahead and add the groups
         * to the layer and the layer to the
         * stage so that the groups have knowledge
         * of its layer and stage
         */
        layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
        layer.add(yodaGroup);
        stage.add(layer);

        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.darthVader,
          width: 200,
          height: 138,
          name: 'image'
        });

        darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');

        darthVaderGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        // yoda
        var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.yoda,
          width: 93,
          height: 104,
          name: 'image'
        });

        yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 104, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 104, 'bottomLeft');

        yodaGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });

        stage.draw();
      }

      var sources = {
        darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg',
        yoda: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg'
      };
      loadImages(sources, initStage);

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an often asked question and the answer is...you can't easily rotate and scale a Kinetic.Image using this anchor technique.  The reason is that the rotation point of a kinetic node is determined by its offset.  When a node is scaled the offset must be recalculated to maintain rotation around the nodes center.

Comment: Thanks markE, I got it working shortly after I posted this but wasnt able to answer my own question saying I did because I am a new user.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: Cool! How did you solve the problem of scale requiring the rotation point to be recalculated?